# Error when trying to authenticate users with google in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been struggling with this for months, sinc.e I'm just learning firebase with flutter.
I have a simple button that when pressed should give the option to register or start section with google, but when running I get errors in the console.

There are so many that I don't know which one it is.

```
Error: Assertion failed:
file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.7.2/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:207:11
options != null
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."

Error: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

[image]

here in onpress of the button:

```
child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            User? user = await Authenticator.IniciarSesion(context: context);
            print(user?.displayName);
          },
```

and the class that authenticates

```
class Authenticator {
  static Future<User?> IniciarSesion({required BuildContext context}) async {
    FirebaseAuth authenticator = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;
    GoogleSignIn objGooglesignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount? objGooglesignInAccount =
        await objGooglesignIn.signIn();

    if (objGooglesignInAccount != null) {
      GoogleSignInAuthentication objGoogleSignInAuthentication =
          await objGooglesignInAccount.authentication;
      AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: objGoogleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: objGoogleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await authenticator.signInWithCredential(credential);
        user = userCredential.user;
        return user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print("error de auth");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if I put a lot of code. I don't know exactly what the error could be.

Comment: The error message tells you what you have to do. Call Firebase.initializeApp. See the Firebase Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your application, first one seems like you are not initializing firebase in the main function properly. Please refer mentioned link for setup.

[Flutter firebase setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

Additionally as I can see there is no firebase_options.dart in your lib directory which basically manages (api key) configurations for different platforms.

If you have followed steps mentioned in guide correctly you can create these configs using

```
flutterfire configure
```

command only after you have already installed flutterfire cli using following command

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```